# Spring - Neo4j Database : Save Enum String to Database and Return as Enum

Tags: java, spring, enums, spring-data-neo4j-4

I want save that Enum in my Database, but only the value, not the name. For example I save object with `CODE_3`, so in my Database, Should be **`ActCode : "3"`**, not `ActCode : "CODE_3"`. But when I find the object, it should be return as **`ActCode.CODE_3`**, not as `String "3"`.

I have an Enum like this :

```
public enum ActCode {

        CODE_3("3"),
        CODE_4("4"),
        CODE_6("6"),
        CODE_7("7"),
        CODE_12("12"),
        CODE_13("13"),
        CODE_14("14"),
        CODE_15("15"),
        CODE_16("16"),
        CODE_17("17"),
        CODE_18("18"),
        CODE_19("19"),
        CODE_20("20"),
        CODE_23("23")

        private String value;

        private ActCode(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.value;
        }
}
```

This is my Class :

```
@NodeEntity
public class TestEnum {

    @GraphId
    Long graphId;

    String id;

    String name;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) 
    ActCode actCode;

}
```

This is how I save my Class in my Service :

```
TestEnum test = new TestEnum("Enum 1",ActCode.CODE_3);
testEnumRepository.save(test);
```

When I look at my Database, this is the result :
[image]

I also tried to use converter, this is my [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert)

I'm using `Spring 4.3.3.RELEASE`, `Hibernate 5.0.11.Final`, `SDN4.1.3-RELEASE`and `neo4j-ogm-2.0.5`.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment using `@Convert` will not apply the converter on `java.util.Enum` as the OGM has a default converter which at the moment, cannot be overridden.

If you need to get something working then you can make `ActCode` a `@NodeEntity` and build the same values for the enum in the database itself.

It's not perfect but it will at least solve the issue till this functionality is added. In the mean time you could raise an enhancement request with the Neo4j OGM Github to allow custom converters to work with enums.

Also FYI: Neo4j-OGM and Spring Data Neo4J do not support JPA annotations like `@Enumerated`.